# Table 'sterling.tbl_marcar' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

Me dice que no existe al momento de insertar los datos, estoy creando una base de datos, de realidad aumentada y inserto los componentes que va a llevar, cada uno tiene un Id_Codigo, luego hago otra tabla tbl_marcas, donde irán los nombres de los componentes, pero en los tres primeros me sale ese error.

```
>     CREATE TABLE tbl_Componente (Id_codigo SMALLINT(3) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
>                    Id_Laboratorio TINYINT(3) NOT NULL, 
>                    Nombre varchar (17) NOT NULL, 
>                    Caracteristicas Text NOT NULL,
>                    Uso Text NOT NULL,
>                    Id_Marca SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,  
>                    Modelo varchar (30) NOT NULL);    
>     
>     
>     Insert Into tbl_Componente (Id_Codigo,Id_Laboratorio,Nombre, Caracteristicas,Uso, Id_Marca, Modelo)
> Values(DEFAULT,142,'Pinzas','Las pinzas son 
>     herramientas metálicas compuestas de dos brazos trabados por un perno que permite abrirlos y volverlos a cerrar. En los extremos de 
>     los brazos se encuentran las mandíbulas las cuales, de acuerdo con su forma, pueden servir para apretar, tensar, cortar o doblar','se 
>     utilizan principalmente para apretar, doblar y sujetar',21,'PPC-6X'); 
>     
>     Insert Into tbl_Componente (Id_Codigo,Id_Laboratorio,Nombre, Caracteristicas,Uso, Id_Marca, Modelo) Values(DEFAULT,143,'Pinzas de
> corte',
>     'se utilizan principalmente para cortar cables y alambres','Sirven también para cortar las patillas de componentes a ras del circuito 
>     impreso una vez soldados. Pueden ser de corte lateral o diagonal',22,'S948'); 
>     
>     Insert Into tbl_Componente (Id_Codigo,Id_Laboratorio,Nombre, Caracteristicas,Uso, Id_Marca, Modelo) Values(DEFAULT,144,'Pinza
> pelacables',
>     'Tienen forma una plana son herramientas metálicas diseñadas para "pelar" y cortar cables.','Se utilizan para cortar y retirar la 
>     cubierta exterior aislante de conductores y cables sin dañar el metal, de manera más eficiente que haciéndolo con una navaja, un
> bisturí 
>     o unos cortafríos',24,'PLC9'); 
>     
>     
>     CREATE TABLE tbl_Marcas (Id_Marca SMALLINT(6) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                Nombre Varchar (255) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO tbl_Marcar VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Truper');
INSERT INTO tbl_Marcar VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Suertek'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_Marcar VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Suertek');
```

Comment: sería ideal para identificar el error que nos muestres editando la pregunta como creaste la tabla, después como tratas de insertar los datos

Comment: Seguro que no escribiste mal el nombre de la tabla en el `INSERT`?

Comment: No, esta bien escrito, ya lo cheque y esta bien

Answer (score 0):

revisando la estructura de tu DDL, me he percatado de que tienes un error entre el como nombras a la tabla y el como insertas los datos, pues, revisando la línea donde creas la tabla la nombras

> tbl_Marcas

Y al momento de realizar la inserción, llamas a la tabla de la siguiente manera

> tbl_Marcar

Por lo que para que tu inserción funcione tendrías que corregirlo de la siguiente manera.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Marcas (
Id_Marca SMALLINT(6) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre Varchar (255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_Marcas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Truper');
INSERT INTO tbl_Marcas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Suertek'); 
INSERT INTO tbl_Marcas VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Suertek');
```